# not able to display employee details in html table in view using json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got problem with displaying employee details in view when the user clicks the button on view..
when the user clicks the button the employee details(both id and name) will be called through the JSON and displaying data in html table, for that purpose I have written like this in my **view**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#submitbtnn').click(function () {
            var table = $('#parenttable');
            var url = '/EmpDetails/GetEmployees/';
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, Val) {
                    var user = '<tr><td>' + Val.EmployeeId + '<td><tr>' + '<tr><td>' + Val.EmployeeName + '<tr><td>'
                    table.append(user);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetEmployeesByName";
}
<h2>GetEmployeesByName</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <table id ="parenttable"></table>    
    <input id="submitbtnn" type="Submit" value="Submit1" />       
}
```

and this is my controller, here i am returning json data to view

```
namespace MvcSampleApplication.Controllers
{
    public class EmpDetailsController : Controller
    {            
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetEmployees()
        {
            List<EmployeeClass> employees = new List<EmployeeClass>();
            EmployeeClass employee1 = new EmployeeClass { EmployeeId=1, EmployeeName = "Rams"};
            EmployeeClass employee2 = new EmployeeClass { EmployeeId = 2, EmployeeName = "joseph" };
            EmployeeClass employee3 = new EmployeeClass { EmployeeId = 3, EmployeeName = "matt" };
            employees.Add(employee1);
            employees.Add(employee2);
            employees.Add(employee3);    
            return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }    
    }
}
```

but I am getting http 404 resource not found error, when i am trying to access this url

```
http://localhost/EmpDetails
```

would any one pls suggest any ideas and any suggestions on this,that would be very greatful to me..

Many thanks...
Modified View

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#submitbtnn').click(function () {            
            var table = $('#parenttable');
            var url = @Url.Action("GetEmployees","EmpDetails")      
           //alert("hi");
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                //alert("hi");
                $.each(data, function (Val) {                       
                    var user = '<tr><td>' + Val.EmployeeId + Val.EmployeeName + '<tr><td>'
                    table.append(user);
                });                   
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetEmployeesByName";
}
<h2>GetEmployeesByName</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <div class="temptable">
       <table id ="parenttable"></table>    
    </div>   
    <input id="submitbtnn" type="Submit" value="Submit1" />
}
```

I am not able to hit second Alert Function inside JavaScript function.

Comment: Is your routing correct?

Comment: Try http://localhost/EmpDetails/GetEmployees

Comment: sorry for late .. I am not able to access the this site ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to cancel the default action of the button by returning false from the click handler:

```
$('#submitbtnn').click(function () {
    var table = $('#parenttable');
    var url = '/EmpDetails/GetEmployees/';
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, Val) {
            var user = '<tr><td>' + Val.EmployeeId + '<td><tr>' + '<tr><td>' + Val.EmployeeName + '<tr><td>'
            table.append(user);
        });
    });

    return false; // <!-- This is very important
});
```

By not canceling the default action, when you click on the submit button, the browser submits the form and redirects away from the page to the `action` of the form leaving no time for the AJAX request to ever execute.

Comment: Many thanks ..but still I am not able to get the results... i will post the code,that I have modified ....

Comment: I am able to display the details but not able to display the header part means emp id and emp table where can I insert the header part would you pls help..

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as your url `@Url.Action("GetEmployees","EmpDetails")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    $('#submitbtnn').click(function () {
        var table = $('#parenttable');

       $.ajax({
            url: 'GetEmployees',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ table: table }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                var rowcount = data.employees.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
                     var user = '<tr><td>' + employees[i].EmployeeId + employees[i].EmployeeName + '<tr><td>'
                     table.append(user);
                 }
                }); 
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('fail');
            }

        });

        return false;
});
```